# Preventing Android 7.0 Nougat from downloading updates over cellular data

Tags: updates, mobile-data, 7.0-nougat

I got a notification this morning on my Nexus 6p informing me that the Android 7.0 Nougat update was ready to download and install on my phone.  The troubling thing about this was the following text:

> Future security updates may be downloaded and installed automatically, possibly using cellular data.

I don't want any updates to download and install over cellular, *ever*.  I am very frugal on my data usage, and normally have cellular data turned off - I turn it on only when I specifically need it.  The wording of the above text is just enough to make me wonder exactly to what lengths Android 7 is going to go to try to download security updates, and what control I am going to have over it, to the point that I'm not going to just allow it to perform this update without knowing more.  However, so far at least documentation on this seems to be hard to come by.

Is it possible to disable security updates over cellular?  I usually have a WiFi connection so it's not like I'm going for days with old software.  If not, will there be some kind of warning so if I am on cellular at the time I can prevent it from downloading until I get to WiFi?

Will Android 7.0 Nougat turn on mobile data even when I have it off just so it can download updates, or is turning off cellular data sufficient to prevent it from doing so?

Comment: I'm not 100% sure, but I found an option in developer options called "Automatic System Updates" - perhaps that can disable it.

Answer (score 1):

This issue already been raised to dev team.

Check ["System update using cellular data"](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/37130318) thread for more details.

> They said its fixed and fix will be pushed in future builds

[image]

But someone already mentioned that its not fixed yet (check date).

[image]

Keep following that thread.

Answer (score 0):

Android won't download updates weather OS or app updates over Mobile network on less you say so or have the option turned on.

Comment: Do you have evidence to back up that this is true specifically in 7.0 Nougat despite the upgrade messages which seem to suggest otherwise?

Comment: This answer is wrong for Android Nougat. My phone downloaded the September security patch without asking. I can see that "Android OS" took 60 MB cellular data in the background.